# Route not found when using Devise's devise_scope

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, web-applications, devise

I am using devise for authentication in my app. My routes file look like this:

```
  devise_scope :user do
    get "/password_reset" => "devise/passwords#new", :as => "new_user_password"
    post "/password_reset/complete" => "devise/passwords#create", :as => "user_password"
    get "/password_renew" => "devise/passwords#edit", :as => "edit_user_password"
    put "/password_renew/complete" => "devise/passwords#update", :as => "password"
  end
```

The full routes.rb file: http://hastebin.com/vofaluhera.coffee

running rake routes show that these route work well:

```
 new_user_password GET  /password_reset(.:format)            devise/passwords#new
     user_password POST /password_reset/complete(.:format)   devise/passwords#create
edit_user_password GET  /password_renew(.:format)            devise/passwords#edit
          password PUT  /password_renew/complete(.:format)   devise/passwords#update
```

However when I visit route /password_reset it rases this error:

```
Could not find devise mapping for path "/password_reset"
```

Also when I switch to devise_for it work fine but with a deprecation warning and it adds more unwanted routes. So basically, I want to stick with devise_scope

Please help me fix this errors.

Edit:
It turns out that I need to add before using devise_scope

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:passwords]
```

Comment: It's strange, can you post all codes in your route.rb?

Comment: Hi Chance Door, thank you for your support. I've updated all codes of routes.rb

Comment: It seems all right. Was "root/password_reset" you visited?